# highcharts vs highstocks - compatible?

Tags: highcharts

I have a number of sites using highcharts and have a licence.
However, I've now been asked to implement 'flags' which are only available in highstocks.

So, if I 'upgrade' to highstocks, will my sites with highcharts continue working as before ?

Or, is there a workaround to create flags in highcharts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highstock contains Highcharts. Simply replace highcharts.js with highstock.js and everything should works the same way.

About flags: you can try to use `scatter` series instead. Simply for marker use image.

Comment: How can I use [this plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/20/Scalable%20Y-Axis) with highstock?